# WinRTXamlToolkit TreeView item stretch horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, treeview, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make tree view item stretch horizontally
Here is my original outcome
[image: Original]
But what I want is this
[image: Altered]

here is my XAML code

```
<Grid x:Name="AgendaGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Controls:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" Style="{StaticResource TouchTreeViewStyle}">
                <Controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                            <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
                        </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>


    <Grid>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding IsHeading}" Padding="0" Content="{Binding Name}" />
  </Grid> 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </Controls:TreeView>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to achieve what you want would be to use the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Unfortunately, that won't work with a `TreeViewItem`. That is because the `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem` features a hard coded top level `Grid` that has the wrong `RowDefinitions` set up for this requirement. Therefore, the way to fulfil your requirement is to alter the default `ControlTemplate`, which you can find in the [TreeView Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Rather than repeat the whole story again here, I'd rather direct you to a solution on the [*Horizontal stretch on TreeViewItems*](http://leecampbell.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html) page of *LeeCampbell's Blog*. That describes the problem in a little more detail and suggests the solution of a simple tweak to the `ControlTemplate`.